# Creating <canvas> based HTML5 text editor

Tags: html, html5-canvas, wysiwyg

I am making a text editor using HTML5 canvas by which I can update text, change fonts, move fonts and move background images.

I need help regarding moving text in canvas - how can it be done using context with mouse move 
events?

Comment: Please don't abuse **bold** formatting. It only makes your question hard to read when you bold the entire thing.

Comment: Check out Carota (earwicker.com/carota). Seems that a canvas based text editor is a realized dream. I haven't used it much yet, but I plan on incorporating it into a site I am building. It persists the text as JSON with formatting attributes. Simple and perfect.

Answer (score 8):

The w3c draft for canvas itself recommends not to do this. You can read this in [canvas best practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#best-practices)

> ```
> Authors should avoid implementing text editing controls using the canvas 
> element. Doing so has a large number of disadvantages
>
> [...]
>
> This is a huge amount of work, and authors are most strongly encouraged 
> to avoid doing any of it by instead using the input element, the textarea 
> element, or the contenteditable attribute.
> ```

If you need a text editor, you could look at other free initiatives like [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)

Comment: thank you for the 'contenteditable', looks to be just what I needed!

Comment: input elements and text areas cannot have arbitrary formatting, and contenteditable support is atrocious on mobile platforms

Comment: When you read the disadvantages from the w3c draft for canvas, it only recommends against it "because it's a lot of work" to rebuild all the features. The w3c doesn't look to know how coders work ! Well, you don't always need all the features, especially for some simple needs. And there are some very nice pure-js implementations.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: This answer was written in 2012. Modern web browsers have come long way since then and the answer no longer holds true. Google Docs and Visual Studio Code both use `<canvas>` based editing. Leaving this answer here just for the sake of the historical purpose. [Here is a good thread on Hacker News on the topic](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27129858).

Using HTML5 `<canvas>` for text edit is not recommended approach (see the answer above fom jbalsas). Mozilla Bespin (Skywriter) was an attempt until it was closed down and the development moved to non-`<canvas>` based ACE editor:

https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/skywriter/

http://ace.ajax.org/

Atom editor choose non-canvas approach, ultimately settling on React.js to speed up DOM update process:

http://blog.atom.io/2014/07/02/moving-atom-to-react.html

However `<canvas>` based editing is possible even if not recommended, see the comments below and the comment from jeromeyers:

http://earwicker.com/carota/

... [also this blog post contains some ideas when DOM based text editing might not work](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/rich-text-editor-in-the-html-canvas-part-1-introducing-carota/).

Comment: I gave this answer a -1 because it's simply not true.  Mozilla *did* do it, and so can anyone else.  Their canvas implementation was full-featured and blazing fast.  They eventually abandoned it because they found a DOM-based implementation was more flexible *for their particular goals*, but that doesn't mean the OP should.  He may have different goals.  If I could, I'd also give this answer another -1 for trying to impress on people that they can't do things that Mozilla can't.  That's simply absurd.

Comment: Yes, let's discourage any work towards anything that has been attempted by anyone before us.  I'm sure that will take us great places.

Comment: If you think is doable I suggest you post an answer how. <canvas> lacks necessary API for mouse events as suggested in the question. Also, <canvas> lacks fine-tuned text rendering making it unsuitable for formatting text. Also, as the other answer in this question state, <canvas> based approach for text controls are not recommended. There are alternatives, so why bang your head to a wall for nothing.

Comment: Canvas supports mouse events. It's up to you to delegate what they do. At some point in any text editor's code, there is a translation from (x,y) of a mouse click to (row,col) in the document. Canvas' text rendering is also fine.  You can always oversample if you need better quality.  I don't believe anyone would 'recommend' the DOM being used for text controls either (outside of input elements/content-editable), but CodeMirror manages to do it quite well.

Comment: Check out Carota (http://earwicker.com/carota/).  Seems that a canvas based text editor is a realized dream.  I haven't used it much yet, but I plan on incorporating it into a site I am building.  It persists the text as JSON with formatting attributes.  Simple and perfect.

Comment: @jeromeyers Did you actually moved on with the idea of forking carota's editor? As it is, it seems to have a lot of performance issues. It would be interesting to see what sort of improvements were made, since the main developer dropped the project a few years back.

Comment: @pelican_george No, I ended up using CodeMirror: https://codemirror.net/

Comment: @jeromeyers May I ask you if you used codemirror for anything else than coding languages?

Comment: @pelican_george Yes, I have.  Check out:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codemirror/BMdcRPweWGY

Comment: @jeromeyers Lively discussion towards the end. =) So you actually implemented a rich text editor on top of it. Since code mirror is most likely to be used as a plain text editor, my I ask you how you've structured your data model and also how you're persisting it?

Comment: GitHub link for SkyWriter https://github.com/mozilla/skywriter